# Perspective image of a cuboid

Tags: geometry, projection

[image]

You are given a perspective image $A'B'C'D'E'F'G'H'$ of a cuboid (rectangular prism) $ABCDEFGH$.  The image is such that in the image, **in any face, opposite sides are not parallel to each other**.  In addition, the measure of the $AE$ (in the cuboid itself) is known.  (Note that $AE = BF = CG = DH $ ).  Can we find the measure of the other two dimensions $AB$ and $BC$ ? (Note that $AB = CD = FE = GH$ and that $BC = DA = EH = GF $)

Comment: Is anything more known about the image than that sides in faces are not parallel? Do we know e.g. some of the *ratios* of the lengths in the image?

Comment: The image is available to you, all the coordinates of all the points $A'$ through $H'$ are available.

Comment: When you say it is a perspective image, does this mean one has projected the actual cuboid from a single point via lines from it to some plane not containing the point?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** - Since I need $H$ for something else, I will label vertices of cuboid differently.

---

Choose a coordinate system where the camera/observer is located at origin $O$.
Let $\mathcal{E} = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{O\}$ and

- $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{E}$ be the target plane of a perspective projection $\eta$ with respect to $O$
- $h$ be the distance between $O$ and $\mathcal{P}$.
- $\hat{h}$ be the unit vector so that $H = H' = h\hat{h}$ is the point on $\mathcal{P}$ closest to $O$.

I will use upper case letters to denote points or directions (vector differences of two distinct point) in $\mathcal{E}$ and add a prime to
denote their images under perspective projection $\eta$ (if possible).

More precisely, let $\mathcal{H}$ be the half-space $\{ P \in \mathbb{R}^3 : P\cdot \hat{h} > h \}$. For any $P \in \mathcal{H}$, we have
$$p = P \cdot \hat{h} > h > 0\quad\text{ and }\quad
P' = \eta(P) = \frac{h}{p} P$$

Consider a cuboid in general orientation in $\mathcal{H}$. Let

- $Q$ be the vertex of cuboid nearest to $\mathcal{P}$
- $A, B, C$ be the three vertices adjacent to $Q$.
- $\bar{Q},\bar{A}, \bar{B}, \bar{C}$ be the vertices opposite to $Q, A, B, C$ respectively.
- $U, V, W$ be the directions $A-Q,B-Q,C-Q$ respectively.

Since the cuboid is in general orientation and $Q$ is the vertex closest to $\mathcal{P}$, we can safely assume:

$$q > h,\quad u = a - q > 0,\quad v = b - q > 0,\quad w = c - q > 0$$

Consider the line $QA = \{ Q + U t : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, it is easy to
see line $Q'A'$, its image under $\eta$, passes through the point $U' = \frac{h}{u}U$ independent of precise location of $Q$.
This means if the perspective image of cuboid is known accurately,
we can locate $U'$ by computing the common intersection of lines $Q'A'$, $B'\bar{C}'$, $C'\bar{B}'$ and $\bar{A}'\bar{Q}'$.
By a similar manner, we can locate $V'$, $W'$.

In the literature, $U',V',W'$ are known as the [vanishing points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point). Once we locate these vanishing points, we can use the fact $U,V,W$ are orthogonal

$$U \cdot V = V \cdot W = W \cdot V = 0
\quad\implies\quad
U' \cdot V' = V' \cdot W' = W' \cdot V' = 0
$$

and
$\begin{cases} 
U' = U' - H' + h\hat{h}\\
V' = V' - H' + h\hat{h}\\
W' = W' - H' + h\hat{h}
\end{cases}$
to deduce
$$
(U' - H')\cdot (V'-H') = (V'- H') \cdot (W'-H') = (W'-H')\cdot (U'-H') = -h^2
\tag{*1}
$$
This in turn implies
$$
(U'-V')\cdot(W' - H') = 
(V'-W')\cdot(U' - H') = 
(W'-U')\cdot(V' - H') = 0
$$
Geometrically, the last set of equations implies $H'$ lies on the common intersection of the three altitudes of $\triangle U'V'W'$ and hence is its
orthocenter (that's why we reserve the symbol $H$ for this point).

Once we know $H'$, we can use $(*1)$ to compute $h$.

Back to the problem of determining the dimensions of cuboid from its image.

Consider the point $A'$ on the line $QU'$, notice
$$ 
Q' = \frac{h}{q}Q,\quad A' = \frac{h}{q+u}(Q+U),\quad U' = \frac{h}{u}U$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
A' - Q' &= \frac{h}{(q+u)q}(q(Q+U) - (q+u)Q) = \frac{h}{(q+u)q}(qU - uQ)\\
U' - A' &= \frac{h}{(q+u)u}((q+u)U-u(Q+U)) = \frac{h}{(q+u)u}(qU-uQ)
\end{align}
$$
This leads to $$\frac{u}{q} = \frac{|A'-Q'|}{|U'-A'|}$$
Together with the fact
$\displaystyle\;|U| = \frac{u}{h}|U'| = \frac{q}{h}\frac{u}{q}\left|(U'-H') + h\hat{h}\right|\;$ and similar arguments for other two directions, we find

$$\bbox[border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1em]{
\begin{align}
|A-Q| = |U| &= \frac{q}{h} \frac{|A'-Q'|}{|U'-A'|}\sqrt{|U'-H'|^2 + h^2}\\
|B-Q| = |V| &= \frac{q}{h} \frac{|B'-Q'|}{|V'-B'|}\sqrt{|V'-H'|^2 + h^2}\\
|C-Q| = |W| &= \frac{q}{h} \frac{|C'-Q'|}{|W'-C'|}\sqrt{|W'-H'|^2 + h^2}
\end{align}
}
$$
As one can see, aside from $q$, everything on RHS can be computed from the
points on $\mathcal{P}$.

- $U',V',W'$ as the vanishing points of the 3 set of images of parallel edges.
- $H'$ as the orthocenter of $\triangle U'V'W'$
- $h$ by equation $(*1)$.

If you know the length of one of the side length, say $|U| = |A - Q|$, you can backout $q$ and get the length of remaining two side lengths $|V|$, $|W|$.

This formula looks horrible but isn't that hard to program. One can represent points and lines in a plane using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The
line passing thru two points or intersection of two lines can be computed using cross product.
For orthocenter $H'$, you can lookup the formula from internet (eg. using [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) or whatever you like). I'll leave the actual details/fun for you.....